# Server Error in '/' .Net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, parse-error, server-error

Might be this question has been asked many times before but I am posting this question because even after referring many posts on stackoverflow, my problem is still not resolved.

Here is my problem:

I built one web service in asp.net with version 3.5 .

And windows server where I am deploying this application having version:

```
 Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18447
```

On localhost, service is working properly but when I am hosting it to on web server I am getting parse error.

You can review error here also:

http://beatjunkie.com.gridhosted.co.uk/DAW.Service/AudioMixingService.asmx

[image: PARSE ERROR IMAGE OF MY APPLICATION]

Here is code snippets of few files:

File: AudioMixingService.asmx

```
   <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="AudioMixingService.asmx.cs" Class="DAW.Service.AudioMixingService" %>
```

File: AudioMixingService.asmx.cs

```
namespace DAW.Service 
{

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

public class AudioMixingService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    //code

 }
}
```

Please kindly help me out what is wrong in running this application on server?

Comment: If this is new development you better look into WCF...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Some points you may like to note:
1. it works on your local server.
2. it says "cannot create type".
which hints, your deployment environment is different. something is not installed, or some DLL files are missing. Perhaps the framework is not installed. If you own the server, use Web Platform installer to check for missing components.

Comment: @Kayson: I have checked out all files are available on server. I think might be development environment is creating an issue. If application is built with version 3.5 then what should be environment version to run application?

Comment: .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 are different. In Windows Server (assuming it is), under Features and Roles, you have to select .NET 3.5.